Invalid refresh token crash Expo Supabase
I am currently developing an app for work with react native, expo and supabase.
The problem i am facing is the following:
ERROR  [AuthApiError: Invalid Refresh Token: Refresh Token Not Found]
Which happens when my session is destroyed, the error itself isnt the problem for me the problem is that my app displays a white screen when getting this error. And i havent found out why it does that.
This is a piece of code related to the error:
    import { supabase } from "@/lib/supabase";
import { AuthApiError, Session } from "@supabase/supabase-js";
import { router } from "expo-router";
import { PropsWithChildren, createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

type AuthData = {
    session: Session | null;
    profile: any;
    loading: boolean;
    isAdmin: boolean;
};

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthData>({
    session: null,
    profile: null,
    loading: true,
    isAdmin: false,
});

export default function AuthProvider({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
    const [newSession, setNewSession] = useState<Session | null>(null);
    const [profile, setProfile] = useState<any>(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);


    useEffect(() => {
      supabase.auth.getSession().then(({ data: { session } }) => {
        setNewSession(session);
        if (session) {
          // Fetch profile when a session exists
          supabase
            .from('profiles')
            .select('*')
            .eq('id', session.user.id)
            .single()
            .then(({ data }) => {
              setProfile(data || null);
              setLoading(false);
            })
        } else {
          console.log('No session found');
          setLoading(false);
          router.push('/(auth)/sign-in');
        }
      });
      
        supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(async (_event, session) => {
          setNewSession(session);

          if (session) {
            // fetch profile
            const { data } = await supabase
              .from('profiles')
              .select('*')
              .eq('id', session.user.id)
              .single();
            setProfile(data || null);
          }
        });
      }, []);

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={{session: newSession, loading, profile, isAdmin: profile?.role === 'ADMIN'}}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

The steps i took to replicate my error:

login to my simulator on my pc, and close app
login to my phone app
logout of my phone (so the session is destroyed)
wait for like 2 hours
open app simulator again and see the error.

If i do this the other way arround i get a white screen on my phone.
I have tried to use a try catch, and to check if there is no session. And if so send the user back to the sign in page. But that didnt prevent my app from crashing.
I am tempted to think that the crash occurs when an error occurs.
I realy hope anyone has some tips for me.
EDIT:

I added my whole code instead of just the useEffect

EDIT 2:
@TommyBs gave me a tip that may would have worked, but i might have done it the wrong way?
Here is the code i made after @TommyBs his tip:
    useEffect(() => {
  // Set up the listener for auth state changes
  const { data: { subscription } } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(
    (event, session) => {
      if (event === 'SIGNED_OUT') {
        // Handle sign out by setting session to null
        setNewSession(null);
        router.push('/(auth)/sign-in');
        setLoading(false);
      } else if (session) {
        // Update the session state if a session is present
        setNewSession(session);
        setLoading(false);
      } else {
        // This handles the case when there is no session (e.g., the user is not logged in)
        setNewSession(null);
        router.push('/(auth)/sign-in');
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
  );

  // Clean up the subscription on component unmount
  return () => {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
  };
}, [router]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (newSession) {
    console.log('session found');
    const fetchProfile = async () => {
      const { data } = await supabase
        .from('profiles')
        .select('*')
        .eq('id', newSession.user.id)
        .single();
      setProfile(data || null);
    }

    fetchProfile();  // Call the async function
  } else {
    console.log(' No session found');
  }
}, [newSession]);

Edit 3:
export default function AuthProvider({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
const [newSession, setNewSession] = useState<Session | null>(null);
const [profile, setProfile] = useState<any>(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  // Set up the listener for auth state changes
  const { data: { subscription } } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(
    (event, session) => {
      if (event === 'SIGNED_OUT') {
        // Handle sign out by setting session to null
        setNewSession(null);
        //router.push('/(auth)/sign-in');
        setLoading(false);
      } else if (session) {
        // Update the session state if a session is present
        setNewSession(session);
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(session);

        // fetch profile
        console.log('session found');
        setTimeout(async () => {
                const { data } = await supabase
                  .from('profiles')
                  .select('*')
                  .eq('id', session.user.id)
                  .single();
                setProfile(data || null);
        }, 0);
      } else {
        // This handles the case when there is no session (e.g., the user is not logged in)
        setNewSession(null);
        //router.push('/(auth)/sign-in');
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
  );



  // Clean up the subscription on component unmount
  return () => {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
  };
}, []);

return <AuthContext.Provider value={{session: newSession, loading, profile, isAdmin: profile?.role === 'ADMIN'}}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>; }
export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

Have you thought about moving your code into a context and using the supabase auth state change listener instead?  Might be a bit easier to manage, especially if you end up with multiple pages/routes. Otherwise if you can display some of your presentation logic as well that might be helpful

@TommyBs I did use context ( i added my whole code so you can see :) )
I havent tried the auth state change listener, i could try that. But i dont see how that would prevent the crash from happening when it wants to refresh the token while there is no active session. But i might be wrong haha, i'll get back to you when i tried it.

The whole issue luckily wasnt because of the error invalid refresh token.
It was part of the issue, but it wasnt the direct cause of the issue.
The issue had to do with the following piece of code:
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
   SpaceMono: require('../../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
   if (loaded) {
   SplashScreen.hideAsync();
   }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
   return null;
  }

If the font didnt load the page never loads and it just shows a white screen.
What fixed my problem was to look up the official way to do this. So i found the following in the docs of expo.
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/
I followed this and used the recommended way of loading the fonts, and hiding the splashscreen. And it Fixed the whole problem for me.
For any questions or needed information just comment and ill explain happily.

I think you've had exactly the same issue I had. You don't need the call to getSession from supabase in your useEffect. Just add an else statement in your auth state change handler to set your state to null as well and rely on that.
I was tearing my hair out over this and unfortunately my question just got downvoted on SO. However on the supabase discord I was pointed out to the fact that calling other supabase functions in the auth state change handler can have side effects - https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-onauthstatechange.
You should wrap the profile fetch in a setTimeout within your authState change when you have a session. Or have another useEffect that uses newSession as a dependency e.g

if (session) {
            // fetch profile
setTimeout(async () => {
            const { data } = await supabase
              .from('profiles')
              .select('*')
              .eq('id', session.user.id)
              .single();
            setProfile(data || null);
  }, 0)
          }





Hey @TommyBs Thanks for your answer, could you take a look at my updated code? It seems to still give me the same error. Invalid Refresh Token: Token not found.
Again to clarify the error isnt the problem but the crash is.

rather than pushing to the router, can you change the main page of your app that consumes the context to do something like:
{!session && (<Text>No session</Text>)
{session && (<Text>Got session</Text>)

Just to see if its the router causing issues? If not do you get an actual error message or just the blank screen? Maybe try using the setTimeout approach rather than a useEffect responding to setSession in your context

I removed the router, and added the conditional text to check if there is a session. But after i log in the newSession state isnt filled in. (Which i can see because of the conditional text)
Is there a way i can achieve that without using the getSession since that is giving problems.
Other than that this looks to be getting me in the right direction.

I assume your contextProvider is wrapping that route component, if you put a console.log in your auth state change handler do they fire to show the new session?

I do see a session now thanks for that tip! The solution i have right now seems to be working. Ill get back to you in a few hours then i'll now for sure if it works.

This wasnt the fix for the problem sadly. The router doesnt appear to be the issue (i disabled all my routers that would have fired because of this). My guess that the issue is that im trying to listen for a session that is not valid anymore (because i am destroying that session with my phone, that because i want to replicate an expired session).
Im just a bit clueless at this point :/, i hope you have any other options on what it could be

i have edited my code in the bottom of the question so you can see what im working with right now.

When you move to your second device after logging out on the first, do you see any kind of log in your auth state change handler then? Does the try/catch not spit out anything meaningful?

Not realy no, the error from the auth state change handler gives me the known. Invalid Refresh Token: Refresh Token Not Found.
Atleast i am guesing that is the cause of the authstatechange listner
